# Why do we add & in the following script, if it does not make any change on the result?

Tags: go

```
package main
import (
  "fmt"
  "math"
    "reflect"
)
type Vertex struct {
  X, Y float64
}
func (v *Vertex) Scale(f float64) {
  v.X = v.X * f
  v.Y = v.Y * f
}
func (v *Vertex) Abs() float64 {
  return math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X + v.Y*v.Y)
}
func main() {
  v := &Vertex{3, 4} // Whether or not with "&", the values don't change below.
  fmt.Printf("Before scaling: %+v, Abs: %v\n", v, v.Abs())
  v.Scale(5)
  fmt.Printf("After scaling: %+v, Abs: %v\n", v, v.Abs())
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(Vertex{3,4}))
}
```

---

Hello, I am learning golang now. I do not understand what is the use of adding "&", if it does not make any change on the result value?

I thought we add "&" to variables to get the memory address. If we can add "&" to Vertex{3,4}, does this mean it is variable? Confused.

Comment: I highly recommend the Tour of Go which explains all these details with lots of examples and exercises.

Comment: See https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1 et seq.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're talking about `Vertex` vs `&Vertex`?  Yes, adding `&` means that `v` now contains an address to a struct of type `Vertex`, whereas without the `&`, `v` would hold the struct directly.

In your example, using the address, or the struct directly, makes no difference.  In many other cases, the distinction is very important.